# Slick Carousel not Working Properly w/ Default Styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='../style.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='//cdn.unreal-designs.co.uk/cont/cdnjslatest/?lib=slick-carousel&file=slick.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href='//cdn.unreal-designs.co.uk/cont/cdnjslatest/?lib=slick-carousel&file=slick-theme.css'>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideCont">

<div class="slider-info">
    <div>Info</div>
    <div>Info2</div>
    <div>Info3</div>
    <div>Info4</div>
</div>
<div class="slider-img">
    <div>Img</div>
    <div>Img2</div>
    <div>Img3</div>
    <div>Img4</div>
</div>

</div>

<script src="//cdn.unreal-designs.co.uk/cont/cdnjslatest/?lib=jquery&file=jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.unreal-designs.co.uk/cont/cdnjslatest/?lib=jquery-migrate&file=jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.unreal-designs.co.uk/cont/cdnjslatest/?lib=slick-carousel&file=slick.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider-info').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-img'
});
$('.slider-img').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-info',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is meant to be like the Slider Syncing sample on here: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ (near the bottom of the examples)

My code can be seen live here: http://new.unreal-designs.co.uk/portfolio/ but the each slide is full width, rendering it rather useless.

*Style.css only contains basic stuff that shouldn't effect the slider in any way.*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after playing around I think I've found the issue. Slick isn't changing the height of the slides to fit the content, thus the slide fills the page -.-

Not sure how to fix this though in JS.